# How to call functor objects's function without invoking call method

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, functor

I have a functor object:

```
private static Func1<MyEvent, Observable<Data>> getDataOnEvent = new Func1<MyEvent, Observable<Data>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<Data> call(MyEvent event) {
        return ApiFactory.get().getData()
    }
};
```

For its invoking I need to do this:

```
result = getDataOnEvent.call(someEvent)
```

Is it possible to do this instead:

```
result = getDataOnEvent(someEvent)
```

Like it is done with Python and Javascript? Maybe a new version of java OR some library like Lombok?

Comment: This kind of functionality is supported in Groovy's closures, but I can't think of anything where it's supported natively in Java.

Comment: You could create a method containing the call, but I think that's not really what you want

Comment: Also supported in Kotlin.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Is it incorrect to think of Kotlin as a wrapper for java? It makes sense to me that Kotlin has this functionality simply because, if my understanding is correct, `getDataOnEvent(someEvent)` is actually just doing `getDataOnEvent.call(someEvent)` behind the scenese.

Comment: @Ishnark - That's exactly what it's doing behind the scenes, but at the JVM level.  Kotlin is just another language that compiles to the JVM.  So it's a sibling of Java, not a wrapper.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

Just use,

```
private static Observable<Data> getDataOnEvent(MyEvent event) {
    return ApiFactory.get().getData()
}
```

and you can call `result = getDataOnEvent(someEvent);` whenever you need it. As you can see, writing it this way, will save even more boiler code than the five letters `.call` on the invocation side.

If `Func1` is a functional interface, you can use `ContainingClass::getDataOnEvent` wherever a `Func1<MyEvent, Observable<Data>>` is expected. You can also store it into a `static` variable, if you prefer using the simple identifier `getDataOnEvent` as function:

```
private static Func1<MyEvent, Observable<Data>> getDataOnEvent
                                              = ContainingClass::getDataOnEvent;
```

Then you can use `getDataOnEvent(event)` to call it or `getDataOnEvent` to refer to it as a `Func1` instance whenever you need it.

If `Func1` is not a functional interface, then you can’t create the function in this compact form, but on the other hand, in that case it wouldn’t be reasonable to ask for a support for calling an arbitrary method without naming it explicitly, either.

Comment: Hi, Holger. after reading your solution I find I can providing another answer to OP, am I right?

Answer (score 1):

I know what you mean, groovy code [call a closure](http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html#_calling_a_closure) like this:

```
def code = { 123 };

//can be called like any other method if the variable is a closure.
assert code() == 123;
//can be call explicitly by using `call` method
assert code.call() == 123;
```

javascript code [call a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) like this:

```
let code = () => 123;

//can be called like any other function if the variable is a function.
assert code() == 123;
//can be call explicitly by using `call` method
assert code.call() == 123;
```

But I can tell you java gammar not support this feature for fields/variables, maybe in the next jdk will be enable this feature which a field/variable refer to [Callable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html).

Fortunately, [Single-Static-Import Declarations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5.3) supports calling a method directly if the **static** member is a method, for example:

```
import static java.lang.Math.abs;

assert abs(-1) == 1;
```

If you really want to make an identifier called like a method call, you can **fake** something like this:

```
class ApiFactory {

    public static Func1<MyEvent, Observable<Data>> getDataOnEvent = new Func1<MyEvent, Observable<Data>>() {
        public Observable<Data> call(MyEvent event) {
            return ApiFactory.get().getData();
        }
    };

    public static Observable<Data> getDataOnEvent(MyEvent event) {
        return getDataOnEvent.call(event);
    }

}
```

then you can call like this:

```
import static ${package}.ApiFactory.getDataOnEvent;
// which is calling a static method
result = getDataOnEvent(event);
// which is calling a static field
result = getDataOnEvent.call(event);
```

Comment: You have always the choice between “a method and a function calling the method” and “a function and a method calling the function”. Since in Java, the function is always a class having a method and the method calling the function is basically calling another method, I prefer defining function the genuine Java way, i.e. a method which contains the code, especially, if the function type is a functional interface which can be implemented via method reference. But even if I consider my variant more natural, it’s worth mentioning the alternative.

Comment: @Holger ^_^, Thank you for giving so much valueable information. I learning more from the comments.